# static block with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, static-block

I am revisiting the concepts of java. So, I am looking in this example

```
 class A {
    A( ) {System.out.print("CA");}
    static {System.out.print("SA");}
}
class B extends  A {
    B() {System.out.print("CB");}
    static {System.out.print("SB");}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

output here is **SASBCACB**

So I didn't understand why CA message is printed since class A constructor is not called.

My question is kind of basic java but its better to know things rather blank about it.

Comment: The constructor in B implicitly calls `super()` which is A's constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is instantiated when you create a `B`, that is how inheritance works.